# Differences between mental health and emotion health

Tags: emotion, mental-illness

I have zero background in psychology and healthcare. Recently I started to read health topics online by googling. I supposed one's health can be broadly categorised into genetic, physical, mental, emotion. Meanings for the first two seem pretty straight forward, but I'm confused with the differences between mental health and emotion health.

Below is one of the few websites that saying mental health and emotion health are not the same:
https://www.pyramidhealthcarepa.com/pyramid-healthcare-assessment-center/pfbh-assessment-center-blog/what-is-the-difference-between-mental-health-emotional-health

> Part of mental health is how well your mind processes and understands information and experiences. In contrast, emotional health involves your ability to manage and express the emotions that arise from what you have learned and experienced.

However, when searching examples of health issues for these two categories, results are substancially overlapping. For instance, depression is listed as an emotion health issue by many websites, but I could also find many other websites that categorise it under mental health issue. Appreciate if someone could shed the light on their differences and give some examples.